# .htaccess redirect string to matching subdirectory and send index file

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

Trying to get:
[www.website.com/name](http://www.website.com/name) to redirect to
[www.website.com/name/index.html](http://www.website.com/name/index.html)

And just showing [www.website.com/name/index](http://www.website.com/name/index), but
`Redirect /name/ /name/index.html` loops the request and gives a 'too many redirects' error in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You get infinite loop  because your pattern `/name/` also matches the target path `/name/index.html` . You need to make it so it doesn't match the target .

You can use `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch /name/$ /name/index.html
```